# Can would have + V3 be used to indicate past possiblity

Tags: grammaticality

It's a bit confusing , well i have read a lot of articles describing how "would have" should be used but most of them has clearly mentioned that it is used to emphasis that the action wasn't done in past .
But could it be possible that it can be used to show possiblity ... in the similar sense might have and must have are used . Like in cases in which we aren't sure if something was done , maybe as a past form of "will have" . What does it imply when it's used as past of "will have" ??

Comment: Please [edit] to explain what a "V3" is. The regulars here at [english.se] aren't always conversant with such abbreviations. Those in the [ell.se] community might be more familiar with them.

Comment: Provide a sentence example, please.

Comment: I agree with @Lawrence.  What is V3?

Comment: Yes, it's called future in the past. Future: *I know I will eat dinner tonight.* Future in the past: *I knew then that I would eat dinner that night.*

Comment: *but most of them clearly mentioned that it is used to emphasis that the action wasn't done in past.* What that means is that the action never happened but, if it had have happened, then it would have happened in the past. "I would have given you the money, but I was robbed." = Although did not give you the money (at that time in the past), my not giving you money was because I was robbed. *Would* can be used to show possibility: "The vase would break if you dropped it."; "would you help me with this question.", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to understand exactly what you're asking (some provided examples within your question would be wonderful), but I think you're mainly asking: **does "would have" strictly imply that the action did not happen, or could it be used if the speaker is unsure if the action happened or not?**

### "Would have" as a conditional

For example in the sentence, "The school **would have** had a ceremony if they had the funding," the speaker knows that the school did not have a ceremony because they did not have the funding. The sentence would be changed if the speaker was unsure about the ceremony. "The school **might have** had a ceremony if they had the funding," is a sentence from a speaker who is unsure if they school had a ceremony; it is also implied that the speaker did not know if the school had the funding.

The above shows "would have" being used because the speaker knows that the event did not happen, in the same context if the speaker is unsure if the event happened, the phrase is changed to "might have"; however, "would have" can be used in a scenario where an event could have possibly happened.

Consider, "If the driver took 5th avenue then he **would have** turned right, otherwise he **would have** turned left." In this sentence, the two events are mutually exclusive and the driver did indeed take one action or the other, so in this case "would have" is being used to describe both an event that did happen and one that did not. The speaker could have also said, "The driver **might have** turned left or right, depending on if they took 5th avenue." Both sentences convey the same message, but they are written differently to correctly use "would have" or "might have".

### "Would have" as the past tense of "will have"

```
Speaker talking in the present: "I know I will have to get to work early tomorrow."
Speaker talking about the past: "I knew I would have to get to work early the next day."
```

The above shows "would have" being used not as a conditional, rather as the past tense of "will have," in which case it is possible the event could have happened.

### Conclusion

So, to answer the question: "Would have" can be used as a past tense of "will have". "Would have" can also be used as a conditional, and whether or not the event in question could have possibly happened is more dependent on the wording that the speaker chose to use and the context of the situation, not strictly based on the usage of "would have."

Comment: No, this is not true. Consider the following: *He **would have** turned left if he came down Fleet Street; otherwise, he **would have** turned right. We'll know soon enough which street he came down and which way he turned.* In that sentence **would have** is entirely conditional—we don't know which of the events happened. You need to qualify or expand your answer.

Comment: @JasonBassford Agreed, thank you. I have updated my answer. I was unable to think of any situations where "would have" could be used for an event that happened, but you certainly provided a valid example. I am now curious is there is a sentence structure where this would work that involved only one use of "would have" as opposed to two uses referring to mutually exclusive events. Food for thought, I suppose.

Comment: You can simply drop the second part of my example: *He **would have** turned left if he came down Fleet Street.* This doesn't say that he did come that way, nor does it say which way he would have turned if he came down a different street.

Comment: I am so sorry I guess i should have added an example to my question , it would have been much better for everyone to understand but now i am rectifying my mistake here is an example - " People have always criticized that show , even it's cast members in most of the interviews can be seen picking it apart . Now you can imagine how messed up the whole show was . " In this last portion i said " how messed up it was " , but it implies that i think show was bad , but if i were to say that I am not sure if it was bad , what should i say . I clearly cann't use "would have"

Comment: @Archit I personally would say "You can imagine that a lot of people disliked the show". Then the speaker would not be implying that he or she disliked the show, they are just simply stating that a lot of people disliked it. But this is no longer a case of "would have." Optionally, the speaker could just be more wordy and specify that they personally have no opinion of the show, "You can imagine how messed up the whole show was to most people; personally, I have no opinion about it"